# i unable to run javafx hello world in browser

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

i unable to run javafx hello world in browser!!!
My Code is

```
public class FxInBrowser extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I have Selected "Run as Browser" in NetBeans.

Thanx in advance

Comment: And what exactly does 'unable' mean in this context?

Comment: Add exception you got if any and your environment details.

Comment: I recommend following Oracle's [Troubleshooting Guide for Java SE 7 Desktop Technologies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/plugin.html).  If it fixes your problem, self-answer your question stating how you fixed your issue.  If you still have an issue, update you question to include the extra diagnostic information you gained by following the guide.

Answer (score 0):

When you launch with browser, you should have html-file generated by NetBeans.

Check, that after clean/build of project you have html file in dist folder.

You should open this HTML file.

If it doesn't work : check that bitness of browser (Chrome - usually 32-bits, Firefox - usually 32-bits) is the same as bitness of your JVM - it is very important.

Also, go to Java options/Advanced in ControlPanel (if Windows, or do similar on other OS), and  switch on Console showing. Usually, all errors are shown there. Try to launch jnlp file too, and look in the Console for possible error, and write them here to investigate the issue.

Applet/jnlp modes of run are always tested and it is verified, that in all public JFX releases these modes are launchable. So, if you cannot launch, you are doing smth in a wrong way.